# Understanding the Addition and Multiplication of the Associated Graded Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, graded-rings

Given a commutative unital ring $R$ and an ideal $I$ of $R,$ one can define a new ring called the *associated graded ring* of $R$ with respect to $I$ $$\operatorname{gr}_I(R) \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \frac R I \oplus \frac I {I^2} \oplus \cdots = \bigoplus_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{I^n}{I^{n + 1}}.$$ We define the multiplication in $\operatorname{gr}_I(R)$ as follows.

> Given any homogeneous elements $\bar r$ and $\bar s$ of $\operatorname{gr}_I(R),$ we have that $\bar r$ is in $I^m / I^{m + 1}$ and $\bar s$ is in $I^n / I^{n + 1}$ for some non-negative integers $m$ and $n.$ Let $r$ and $s$ denote the representatives of $\bar r$ and $\bar s$ in $I^m$ and $I^n,$ respectively. We define $rs$ to be the equivalence class of $\bar r \bar s$ in $I^{m + n} / I^{m + n + 1}.$ Observe that this is well-defined modulo $I^{m + n + 1}.$ We may multiply inhomogeneous elements of $\operatorname{gr}_I(R)$ by using the distributive property.

Generally, there is not a ring homomorphism $R \to \operatorname{gr}_I(R);$ however, there is always a set-theoretic map $-^* : R \to \operatorname{gr}_I(R)$ defined as follows. Given an element $r$ of $R,$ consider the quantity $\operatorname{ord}(r) = \sup \{n \,|\, r \in I^n \}.$ We define $r^*$ to be the equivalence class of $r$ in $I^{\operatorname{ord}(r) + 1}$ whenever $\operatorname{ord}(r)$ is finite and $r^* = 0$ otherwise. We refer to $r^*$ as the *initial form* of $r.$ Every homogeneous element of $\operatorname{gr}_I(R)$ is of the form $r^*$ for some element $r$ in $R.$

Chapter 5, Section 1 of Eisenbud's *Commutative Algebra* discusses the associated graded ring of $R$ in some detail; however, I am not comfortable enough with the material to solve the exercises on my own. Particularly, I would like to solve Exercise 5.1, which states that either $r^* + s^* = (r + s)^*$ or $r^* + s^* = 0$ and either $r^* s^* = (rs)^*$ or $r^* s^* = 0.$

Ultimately, I would like to understand the following questions.

> 1.) What is the addition operation in $\operatorname{gr}_I(R)?$
>
> 2.) Why does the initial form map fail to be a ring homomorphism?
>
> 3.) Under what conditions is it guaranteed that $r^* + s^* = (r + s)^*?$
>
> 4.) If $\operatorname{gr}_I(R)$ is a domain, then by Eisenbud's exercise, we have that $r^* s^* = (rs)^*.$ Under what other conditions is it guaranteed that $r^* s^* = (rs)^*?$

Thanks in advance for your time and consideration.

Comment: One other description of $\operatorname{gr}_I(R)$ is as the quotient of the Rees ring $R[It]$ by the ideal $IR[It].$ Eisenbud's example in the text is $R = k[x, y]$ and $I = [x, y],$ but this doesn't shed much light on my questions because $\operatorname{gr}_I(R) \cong R[It] / IR[It] = k[x, y, xt, yt] / (xt, yt) \cong k[x, y],$ so nothing funky happens here to illustrate the behavior in my questions.

Comment: I take it that a homogeneous element is an element with support in exactly one component of the direct sum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that each $I^n/I^{n+1}$ is an abelian group (in fact an $R$-module). So $\bigoplus_{n \ge 0} I^n/I^{n+1}$ inherits an abelian group structure from these. In particular, if $a=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} r_n$ and $b=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} r'_n$ with $r_n,r'_n \in I^n/I^{n+1}$ and only finitely many $r_n$'s and $r'_n$'s nonzero, then $a+b=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} (r_n+r_n')$.

The initial form map is not additive even in the nicest of circumstances. For example, take $R=k[\![x]\!]$ (or $R=k[x]$), and $I=(x)$. Then $\operatorname{gr}_I(R) \cong k[x]$. Let $a=x+x^2$ and $b=-x+x^3$.  Then $a^*=x$ and $b^*=-x$.  But $(a+b)^*=x^2+x^3$ while $a^*+b^*=0$. You should be careful, however, the exercise you mention asks you to prove something false. Indeed, we could also take $a=x$ and $b=x^2$. Of course, $a^*=x$ and $b^*=x^2$, but $(a+b)^*=(x+x^2)^*=x$. Perhaps the best amendment to the exercise is to add the assumption that $r^*$ and $s^*$ have the same degree.

In fact, additivity holds for all $r,s \in R$ if and only if $I=I^2$. Indeed, if $x \in I-I^2$, then we set $a=-1$ and $b=1+x$. We have $a^*=-1$ and $b^*=1$ so $a^*+b^*=0$ while $(a+b)^*=x^* \ne 0$. The case where $I=I^2$ is easy to verify. Of course, in this case, the associated graded ring is just $R/I$ and the initial form map the natural surjection $R \to R/I$, so it's not super interesting.

The takeaway from this is that the initial form map is never meaningfully a homomorphism.

Comment: Essentially, then, we add elements of $\operatorname{gr}_I(R)$ componentwise? But what if we have elements that are not of the same degree (e.g., an element $r$ from $I^m / I^{m + 1}$ and an element $s$ from $I^n / I^{n + 1}$ with $n > m$)? Where would the sum $r + s$ live? Would it necessarily live in $I^n / I^{n + 1}?$ If it lived in $I^m / I^{m + 1},$ then as we have assumed that $n \geq m + 1,$ we have that $I^n \subseteq I^{m + 1}$ so that $r + s + I^{m + 1} = r + I^{m + 1},$ and dropping the coset notation would give that $r + s = r.$

Comment: I also notice that both you and Eisenbud drop the coset notation. For multiplication, it is understood that if $r$ is in $I^m / I^{m + 1}$ and $s$ is in $I^n / I^{n + 1},$ then $rs$ is in $I^{m + n} / I^{m + n + 1},$ but for addition, I am still uncertain. I appreciate very much your thoughtful solution.

Comment: I am also not sure what an inhomogeneous element of  $\operatorname{gr}_I(R)$ would look like. I guess I am actually not sure what is meant by a homogeneous element. I keep thinking in terms of polynomials, but I fear that this is not the correct way to understand the associated graded ring.

Comment: @Carlo Perhaps if we switch notation momentarily it will help you; suppose $A=\bigoplus^{\infty}_{i=0} A_i$ is an $\mathbb{N}$-graded commutative ring, so each $A_i$ is an abelian group.  An element of $A$ has the form $(a_1,a_2,\dots,)$ where all but finitely many $a_i$ are nonzero. A homogeneous element of $A$ is an element $a=(a_1,a_2,\dots)$ where at most one of the $a_i$ is nonzero.  Addition is componentwise, so if $a=(a_1,a_2,\dots)$ and $b=(b_1,b_2,\dots)$ then $a+b=(a_1+b_1,a_2+b_2,\dots)$.

Comment: @Carlo For example, say we have homogeneous elements $a=(a_1,0,0,\dots)$ and $b=(0,b_2,0,0,\dots)$.  Then $a+b=(a_1,b_2,0,0,\dots)$. In formal summation notation, we just write $a_1$ for $a$ and $b_2$ for $b$ and then $a+b=a_1+b_2$ and that's it, there's no simplification to perform. This generalizes the familiar polynomial ring case. For example, taking $k[x]$ with the standard grading, $x^2$ and $x^3$ are homogeneous elements, but $x^2+x^3$ is not homogeneous.

Comment: @Carlo So for your associated graded ring $\operatorname{gr}_I(R)$, if we have homogeneous elements $r \in I^n/I^{n+1}$ and $s \in I^m/I^{m+1}$, then the sum is the usual sum inside of $I^n/I^{n+1}$ if $m=n$ and is the formal sum $r+s$ otherwise, which we could also write as an infinite tuple with $r$ in the $n$th spot and $s$ in the $n$th.

Comment: I see. Very helpful commentary! Now, what is the deal with $r^* + s^*?$ Like you mention, if these don't belong to the same graded piece of $\operatorname{gr}_I(R),$ then it does not really make sense to add these things together, right? But as you suggest, if $r^*$ and $s^*$ live in the same graded piece, then their sum will just be $(r + s)^*$ or $0^*.$

Comment: @Carlo This discussion is starting to become extended; let me suggest moving it to chat.